# PaintCode 2 - Can't modify constraints?

Tags: paintcode

I can't modify constraints using PaintCode 2. 
[image]

After selecting group or a single shape I am clicking on constraints I want to change but nothing happens. 
Anyone knows how to deal with it???

Comment: Adding a frame around your shape will allow you to add constraints.

Comment: Of course. I feel like an idiot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you need to add a frame to the canvas for constraints to be available.